# rspec triggers "DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, scaffolding

I followed the tutorial at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html with scaffolding and added rspec. I didn't add any special code so far.

When doing...

```
rake spec
```

... I get around 20 of the following warnings:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside
>   ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically.
>   Please define instance methods directly in
>   RSpec::Rails::ViewExampleGroup instead. (called from 
>   at
>   /Users/pixtur/Projects/website-com/spec/views/welcome/index.html.haml_spec.rb:3)

I don't understand, what this error is trying to tell me. `index.html.haml_spec.rb` was created by scaffolding and looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "welcome/index.html.haml" do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

I'm using `rails 3.2.3 / ruby 1.9.2`

I have to following gems installed:

- actionmailer (3.2.3)
- actionpack (3.2.3)
- activemodel (3.2.3)
- activerecord (3.2.3)
- activeresource (3.2.3)
- activesupport (3.2.3)
- acts-as-taggable-on (2.2.2)
- addressable (2.2.8)
- arel (3.0.2)
- autotest-rails (4.1.2)
- builder (3.0.0)
- bundler (1.1.3)
- capistrano (2.12.0)
- capybara (1.1.2)
- childprocess (0.3.2)
- coffee-rails (3.2.2)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
- diff-lcs (1.1.3)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (1.4.0)
- ffi (1.0.11)
- haml (3.1.6)
- haml-rails (0.3.4)
- highline (1.6.12)
- hike (1.2.1)
- i18n (0.6.0)
- journey (1.0.3)
- jquery-rails (2.0.2)
- json (1.7.3)
- libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-darwin-10)
- libwebsocket (0.1.3)
- mail (2.4.4)
- mime-types (1.18)
- mini_magick (3.4)
- multi_json (1.3.5)
- mysql (2.8.1)
- net-scp (1.0.4)
- net-sftp (2.0.5)
- net-ssh (2.5.2)
- net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
- nokogiri (1.5.2)
- polyglot (0.3.3)
- rack (1.4.1)
- rack-cache (1.2)
- rack-ssl (1.3.2)
- rack-test (0.6.1)
- rails (3.2.3)
- railties (3.2.3)
- rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
- rdoc (3.12)
- rspec (2.6.0)
- rspec-core (2.6.4)
- rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
- rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
- rspec-rails (2.6.1)
- rubygems-update (1.8.24)
- rubyzip (0.9.8)
- rvm (1.11.3.3)
- rvm-capistrano (1.2.2)
- sass (3.1.19)
- sass-rails (3.2.5)
- selenium-webdriver (2.21.2)
- sprockets (2.1.3)
- subexec (0.2.2)
- therubyracer (0.10.1)
- thor (0.14.6)
- tilt (1.3.3)
- treetop (1.4.10)
- tzinfo (0.3.33)
- uglifier (1.2.4)
- xpath (0.1.4)
- ZenTest (4.8.0)

Any help on how to get rid of the warning are strongly welcome.

Answer (score 7):

The warnings vanished after upgrading to the latest versions of rspec:

rspec (2.10.0)
rspec-core (2.10.1)
rspec-expectations (2.10.0)
rspec-mocks (2.10.1)
rspec-rails (2.10.1)

Comment: rspec 2.14 did not fix this for me