# Why won't Bundler let me update a few gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, gemfile

I'm trying to eliminate these annoying DEPRECATION WARNINGS whenever I try to run rspec tests (I'm trudging through the Rails tutorial).

I tried following the suggestion here: [rspec triggers "DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770160/rspec-triggers-deprecation-warning-the-instancemethods-module-inside-activesup) to simply update my versions of rspec.

However, whenever tried that, I would end up with a message like this:

```
The bundle currently has rspec-core locked at 2.1.0.
Try running `bundle update rspec-core`
```

or this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-core":
  In Gemfile:
    rspec-rails (= 2.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      rspec-core (~> 2.1.0) x86-mingw32

    rspec-core (2.10.1)
```

Finally, I just went ahead and hit `bundle install` to update ALL my gems.  However, that produced the wonderful result of not updating those rspec's.  What's going on?  (And I've been updating my commits to my current git branch along the way.)

Thank you.

Edit: Here is what my gemfile and gemfile.lock look like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.1.0' #NOTICE: possible error with rails version
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'    
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

And my gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      arel (~> 3.0.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
    activesupport (3.2.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.3.7)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.6)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    ffi (1.3.1-x86-mingw32)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.6)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.20.1)
    multi_json (1.5.0)
    nokogiri (1.5.6-x86-mingw32)
    pg (0.12.2-x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.4)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      activerecord (= 3.2.1)
      activeresource (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.1)
    railties (3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.1.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.1.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.1.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.1.0)
    rspec-core (2.1.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.1.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.1.0)
    rspec-rails (2.1.0)
      rspec (~> 2.1.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.29.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5-x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  capybara (= 1.1.2)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.2)
  jquery-rails (= 2.0.2)
  pg (= 0.12.2)
  rails (= 3.2.1)
  rspec-rails (= 2.1.0)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.5)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.5)
  uglifier (= 1.2.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tough to answer exactly without seeing the Gemfile, but the message indicates that you were depending on version 2.10.1 of rspec-core in your Gemfile, but you were also depending on rspec-rails 2.1.0 which depended on rspec-core `~> 2.1.0`, which means rspec-core version 2.1.0-2.1.x. With `~>` and a patch level version number, the patch version (last number) can be same or higher as what is specified, but not the minor version (second number) or major version (first number).

The fix is to just remove rspec/rspec-core from your Gemfile if you have rspec-rails defined in it, and rspec-core will get loaded in by rspec-rails. At time of writing (2013-02-06), the latest rspec-rails is 2.12.2, so you might want to use: `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.12.2'` and then update your tests to use the latest syntax. That way you are up-to-date, but if you use `bundle update` later, it will update if the new version is 2.12.3 or later, but it won't update to 2.13.x or later, since that version might be incompatible with your tests.

For more info, read:

- Gem versions: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74
- Bundler documentation: http://gembundler.com/

Answer (score 1):

Because of the version requirement you need to update both gems at the same time.

Try:
`bundle update rspec-rails rspec-core`

Edit:

Thank you for posting your Gemfile. The real problem is that you have locked your rspec-rails version.

Change the line:

`gem 'rspec-rails', '2.1.0'`

to

`gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.12.2'`

After which `bundle update rspec-rails`  should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Evan's answer should work for you but to explain the next part of your question...

bundle install is going to use your current Gemfile.lock to install the gems. The Gemfile.lock is generated the first time you do a bundle install and updated when you do a bundle update. So, if you do a

```
 bundle update
```

it will update your Gemfile.lock with a freshly generated dependency tree. That should resolve your problem here.

Comment: This will work, but also possibly produce undesired gem upgrades.