# Bundler won't let me install gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to eliminate these annoying DEPRECATION WARNINGS whenever I try to run rspec tests (I'm trudging through the Rails tutorial).

I tried following the suggestion here: [rspec triggers "DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770160/rspec-triggers-deprecation-warning-the-instancemethods-module-inside-activesup) to simply update my versions of rspec.

However, whenever tried that, I would end up with a message like this:

```
The bundle currently has rspec-core locked at 2.1.0.
Try running `bundle update rspec-core`
```

or this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-core":
  In Gemfile:
    rspec-rails (= 2.1.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      rspec-core (~> 2.1.0) x86-mingw32

    rspec-core (2.10.1)
```

Finally, I just went ahead and hit `bundle install` to update ALL my gems.  However, that produced the wonderful result of not updating those rspec's.  What's going on?  (And I've been updating my commits to my current git branch along the way.)

Thank you.

Edit: Here is what my gemfile and gemfile.lock look like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.1.0' #NOTICE: possible error with rails version
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'    
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

And my gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.4.0)
    actionpack (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.2)
    activemodel (3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      arel (~> 3.0.0)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.1)
      activemodel (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
    activesupport (3.2.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    capybara (1.1.2)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 0.1.4)
    childprocess (0.3.7)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.6)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    ffi (1.3.1-x86-mingw32)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.6)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.20.1)
    multi_json (1.5.0)
    nokogiri (1.5.6-x86-mingw32)
    pg (0.12.2-x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.4)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      activerecord (= 3.2.1)
      activeresource (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.1)
    railties (3.2.1)
      actionpack (= 3.2.1)
      activesupport (= 3.2.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.1.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.1.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.1.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.1.0)
    rspec-core (2.1.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.1.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.1.0)
    rspec-rails (2.1.0)
      rspec (~> 2.1.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.29.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5-x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    xpath (0.1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  capybara (= 1.1.2)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.2)
  jquery-rails (= 2.0.2)
  pg (= 0.12.2)
  rails (= 3.2.1)
  rspec-rails (= 2.1.0)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.5)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.5)
  uglifier (= 1.2.3)
```

Comment: Have you attempted to delete your `gemfile.lock` and re-run the `bundle` command. What is the output after this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem here that you need to simply do the following

```
sudo gem uninstall rspec-core -v 2.2.1
bundle update rspec-core
```

This maybe required for other dependent gems like (rspec-rails, rspec)

Check this by by doing `gem list rspec`

Comment: I had the some problem with sprockets 3.7.0. Actually I uninstalled sprocket 3.7.0 by `gem list sprockets; gem uninstall sprockets; Choose the one you want to uninstall`. But I got the error `The bundle currently has sprockets locked at 3.7.0.` But after I `bundle update sprockets` as @David suggested. Everything works like a charm.